# How to remove the Pop up message coming from FCKEditor when we paste text from a word file

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

I am using FCK Editor and when I try to paste some code from word in the editor, I get some pop up messages as follows:-

1)**"Because of your browser security settings,the editor is not able to access your clipboard data directly. You are required to paste it again in this window.

Please paste inside the following box using the keyboard (Ctrl+V) and hit OK."**

2) **"The text you want to paste seems to be copied from Word. Do you want to clean it before pasting?"**

These two messages are displayed on two different machines.

I don't want both these popups. I want to allow user to paste text from word without these popups

Please provide me a solution to resolve this issue, so that I can paste text from word files also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These pop-ups are there for a reason. Getting content from the clipboard is rightly generally impossible in JavaScript so browser-based rich text editors have to work round this as best they can. I know that CKEditor (FCKeditor's replacement) uses a trick that redirects a user paste to an offscreen element, which gives the editor access to pasted content before it's inserted into the editor; I think this trick may not be implemented in FCKeditor, so you may want to consider trying CKEditor.

Comment: My users see this message as well, and we're using CKEditor. Any ideas?
Why does any script need access to the clipboard, what's wrong with allowing the browser to just paste?

Comment: @gidireich: Rich text editors provide features to paste content as plain text or to "clean" it of styles and elements that results from copying from Microsoft Word. To do this, they need to isolate the content that was pasted. If the default browser paste is allowed to proceed, it is extremely difficult to extract the content pasted reliably in all circumstances, hence it is desirable to get it directly from the clipboard. As to why you get this message in CKEditor, I'm not sure: I'd have to look around the CKEditor source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this add-on for Firefox
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/allowclipboard-helper/

Reference: http://support.mozilla.org/questions/754412‎

Comment: This add-on has been removed by its author.